# NSDictionary to Multidimensional Array ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multidimensional-array, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary with values like

```
@{@"key1":@[@"value",@"value",@"value"],@"key2":@[@"value",@"value"],@"key3":@[@"value",@"value",@"value",@"value"]}
```

and i convert this dictionary to array using following method

```
+(NSMutableArray *)getTableNameandColumnValues{
NSMutableArray *uploadTableArrray =[NSMutableArray new];
 uploadMasterTableDataDictionary = uploadMasterValues;


NSArray *keys = [[uploadMasterTableDataDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];;


for(id key in keys) {
    id value = [uploadMasterTableDataDictionary objectForKey: key];
    [uploadTableArrray addObject:key];
    [uploadTableArrray addObject:value];

}
  NSLog(@"uploadTableArrray %@",uploadTableArrray);

return uploadTableArrray;
}
```

its return the array like

```
( key1,
    (
    value,
    value,
    value,
    value

),key2,
    (
    value,
    value,

    ),key3,
    (
    value,
    value,
    value
    ))
```

but i need a array like

```
( (key1,
    "value,value,value,value"

),(key2,
    "value,value"
),(key3,
    "value,value,value"))
```

how can i get like this

Comment: In other words, you want the key embedded inside the array against that key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for(id key in keys) {
    NSArray *value = uploadMasterTableDataDictionary[key];
    NSMutableArray *subArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [subArray addObject:key];
    [subArray addObjectsFromArray:value];
    [uploadTableArrray addObject:subArray];
}
```

As pointed-out by @NSNoob, it looks like you might want the value to be a single, comma-separated, string.  If that's true then use this instead:

```
for(id key in keys) {
    NSArray *value = uploadMasterTableDataDictionary[key];
    [uploadTableArrray addObject:@[key, [value componentsJoinedByString:@","]]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the value against the key is already an array. When you add it to `uploadTableArrray`, it will have two objects. One will be the array and second will be the key. So the output is right as per your logic.

However to get your requirement, you have to change it like this:

```
for(id key in keys) {
    NSMutableArray *value = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[uploadMasterTableDataDictionary objectForKey: key]];
    //[uploadTableArrray addObject:key]; Remove this line
    //[uploadTableArrray addObject:value]; and This one should go as well
    NSMutableArray *valueArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [valueArr addObject:key];
    [valueArr addobjectsFromArray:value];
    [uploadTableArrray addObject:valueArr];

}
```

But now looking again at your question makes me think you want the value array to be presented as one string by combining all the objects in that array. To do that you have to use this:

```
for(id key in keys) {
        NSMutableArray *value = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[uploadMasterTableDataDictionary objectForKey: key]];
        NSString *valueCombinedString = @"";
        if(value.count>0)
        {
            valueCombinedString = [[value valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        }

        //[uploadTableArrray addObject:key]; Remove this line
        //[uploadTableArrray addObject:value]; and This one should go as well
        NSMutableArray *valueArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [valueArr addObject:key];
        [valueArr addobject:valueCombinedString];//valueCombinedString will now contain all the values in the array as one string
        [uploadTableArrray addObject:valueArr]; //valueArr will now have only two strings. One will be the key and second will be the valueCombinedString

    }
```

Comment: I think you might be right, however you can cut that code down considerably using `[NSArray componentsSeparatedByString:]`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I think you mean `[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:]`? Thanks for the hint I have implemented that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace for loop as mentioned below:

```
for(id key in keys) {
    id value = [dict objectForKey: key];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array addObject:key];
    [array addObjectsFromArray:value];

    [uploadTableArrray addObject:array];
}
```

Hope this helps!